# when using Watchman's watch-make I want to access the name of the changed files

Tags: python, watchman

I am writing a watchman command with watchman-make and I'm at a loss when trying to access exactly what was changed in the directory. I want to run my upload.py script and inside the script I would like to access filenames of newly created files in /var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS .
so far I have

```
$ watchman-make -p '/var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS' -—run 'python /home/pi/upload.py'
```

I'd like to add another argument to python upload.py so I can have an exact filepath to the newly created file so that I can send the new file over to my database in upload.py,

I've been looking at the docs of watchman and the closest thing I can think to use is a trigger object. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `watchman-wait`:

Assuming project layout like this:

```
/posts/_SUBDIR_WITH_POST_NAME_/index.md
/Scripts/convert.sh
```

And the shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: convert.sh

SrcDirPath=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")/../"; pwd)
cd "$SrcDirPath"

echo "Converting: $SrcDirPath/$1"
```

Then we can launch `watchman-wait` like this:

```
watchman-wait . --max-events 0 -p 'posts/**/*.md' | while read line; do ./Scripts/convert.sh $line; done
```

When we changing file `/posts/_SUBDIR_WITH_POST_NAME_/index.md` the output will be like this:

```
...
Converting: /Users/.../Angular/dartweb_quickstart/posts/swift-on-android-building-toolchain/index.md
Converting: /Users/.../Angular/dartweb_quickstart/posts/swift-on-android-building-toolchain/index.md
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`watchman-make` is intended to be used together with tools that will perform a follow-up query of their own to discover what they want to do as a next step.   For example, running the `make` tool will cause make to `stat` the various deps to bring things up to date.

That means that your `upload.py` script needs to know how to do this for itself if you want to use it with watchman.

You have a couple of options, depending on how sophisticated you want things to be:

## Use pywatchman to issue an ad-hoc query

If you want to be able to run `upload.py` whenever you want and have it figure out the right thing (just like `make` would do) then you can have it ask watchman directly.  You can have `upload.py` use `pywatchman` (the python watchman client) to do this.  `pywatchman` will get installed if the the watchman `configure` script thinks you have a working python installation.  You can also `pip install pywatchman`.  Once you have it available and in your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
import pywatchman

client = pywatchman.client()
client.query('watch-project', os.getcwd())
result = client.query('query', os.getcwd(), {
   "since": "n:pi_upload",
   "fields": ["name"]})
print(result["files"])
```

This snippet uses the *since generator* with a *named cursor* to discover the list of files that changed since the last query was issued using that same named cursor.  Watchman will remember the associated *clock* value for you, so you don't need to complicate your script with state tracking.  We're using the name `pi_upload` for the cursor; the name needs to be unique among the watchman clients that might use named cursors, so naming it after your tool is a good idea to avoid potential conflict.

This is probably the most direct way to extract the information you need without requiring that you make more invasive changes to your upload script.

## Use pywatchman to initiate a long running subscription

This approach will transform your `upload.py` script so that it knows how to directly subscribe to watchman, so instead of using `watchman-make` you'd just directly run `upload.py` and it would keep running and performing the uploads.  This is a bit more invasive and is a bit too much code to try and paste in here.  If you're interested in this approach then I'd suggest that you take the code behind `watchman-wait` as a starting point.  You can find it here:

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/python/bin/watchman-wait

The key piece of this that you might want to modify is this line:

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/python/bin/watchman-wait#L169

which is where it receives the list of files.

## Why not triggers?

You could use triggers for this, but we're steering folks away from triggers because they are hard to manage.  A trigger will run in the background and have its output go to the watchman log file.  It can be difficult to tell if it is running, or to stop it running.

The interface is closer to the unix model and allows you to feed a list of files on stdin.

## Speaking of unix, what about `watchman-wait`?

We also have a command that emits the list of changed files as they change.  You could potentially stream the output from `watchman-wait` in your `upload.py`.  This would make it have some similarities with the subscription approach but do so without directly using the pywatchman client.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I ended up making another directory called .archived, and in my script I check the contents of the watched directory, then upload them to my database and then move the contents to the archived dir so that next time I list the contents only new files go through the process. Works like a charm so far!